# Problem when converting DataFrame to DynamicFrame

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a code that converts DataFrame to DynamicFrame and I get this weird error when trying to execute return statement, any clues what's going on?

Error:
`{AttributeError}'str' object has no attribute '_jvm'`

```
# record is DynamicFrame
def extractCustomFields(record, ctx):
    rec = record.toDF()
    rec = rec.withColumn("lastname", rec["customfields"][0].value)
    rec.show()
return DynamicFrame.fromDF(rec, ctx, "recordTransform")
```

Comment: `fromDF(dataframe, glue_ctx, name)` takes `GlueContext` as second param and you are passing `str`. Is your `GlueContext` initialized properly? Please see: [fromDf](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-fromDF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromDF()` expects the GlueContext as second argument. You need to pass that:

```
return DynamicFrame.fromDF(rec, ctx, "recordTransform")
```

Comment: yes I was passing transformationContext instead of GlueContext